# How to print/return the softmax score in Keras during training?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

Question: How do I print/return the softmax layer for a multiclass problem using Keras?

- my motivation: it is important for visualization/debugging.
- it is important to do this for the 'training' setting. ergo batch normalization and dropout must behave as they do in train time.
- it should be efficient. calling vanilla model.predict() every now and then is less desirable as the model I am using is heavy and this is extra forward passes. The most desirable case is finding a way to simply display the original network output which was calculated during training.
- it is ok to assume that this is done while using Tensorflow as a backend.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the outputs of any layer by using: model.layers[index].output

For all layers use this:

```
from keras import backend as K

inp = model.input                                  # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers] # all layer outputs
functor = K.function([inp]+ [K.learning_phase()], outputs ) # evaluation function

# Testing
test = np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
layer_outs = functor([test, 1.])
print layer_outs
```